# js function only works sometimes in firefox but works all the time in my other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

so the add to cart function only works sometimes in firefox but other browsers work fine

changing some of the listener code

```js
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

//-----------------


function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText

    var selectedValue = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-list')[0]
    var selectedSize = selectedValue.options[selectedValue.selectedIndex].text

    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc, selectedSize)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc, selectedValue) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
     var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-list')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
```

its meant to add the item to cart 
https://www.jagsblast.xyz/public/rio-roller2.html

Comment: If you look in the developer tools in firefox, are there any JavaScript console errors? That could help you. Here is how to open the developer tools in firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools#The_Core_Tools

Comment: Line 8 has a '}'
If you remove it, maybe it works!

Comment: There's also a missing closing `}` in the last function. Maybe you're calling it too early, so in Firefox sometimes the document is ready and sometimes it isn't. Or is it the listener that isn't working?

Comment: You should better check elements you are on - sometimes there are small differences in some browsers - like a text, BR, etc. you do not see or have different # or order in another. For example when setting shopItem, I would make a null check (in case) and check if I am on element I am looking for - 2 parents up may not work same each time/browser/page.